# Dump and restore of PostgreSQL database with hstore comparison in view fails

Tags: postgresql, hstore, postgresql-9.3, pg-restore

I have a view which compares two `hstore` columns.

When I dump and restore this database, the restore fails with the following error message:

```
Importing /tmp/hstore_test_2014-05-12.backup...
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 172; 1259 1358132 VIEW hstore_test_view xxxx
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  operator does not exist: public.hstore = public.hstore
LINE 2:  SELECT NULLIF(hstore_test_table.column1, hstore_test_table....
                ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
    Command was: CREATE VIEW hstore_test_view AS
 SELECT NULLIF(hstore_test_table.column1, hstore_test_table.column2) AS "nullif"
   FROM hst...
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  relation "hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_view" does not exist
    Command was: ALTER TABLE hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_view OWNER TO xxxx;
```

I was able to create this error in PostgreSQL 9.3.0 with the following steps:

```
CREATE DATABASE hstore_test;

\c hstore_test

CREATE EXTENSION hstore WITH SCHEMA public;

CREATE SCHEMA hstore_test_schema;

CREATE TABLE hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_table(
   id int,
   column1 hstore,
   column2 hstore,
   PRIMARY KEY( id )
);

CREATE VIEW hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_view AS
SELECT NULLIF(column1, column2) AS comparison FROM hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_table;
```

For completeness, the dump and restore process looked like this:

```
pg_dump -U xxxx -h localhost -f /tmp/hstore_test_2014-05-12.backup -Fc hstore_test
psql -U xxxx -h localhost -d postgres -c "DROP DATABASE hstore_test"
psql -U xxxx -h localhost -d postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE hstore_test"
pg_restore -U xxxx -h localhost -d hstore_test /tmp/hstore_test_2014-05-12.backup
```

`pg_restore -l /tmp/hstore_test_2014-05-12.backup` suggests that the `hstore` extension is enabled before the view is created:

```
;
; Archive created at Mon May 12 11:18:32 2014
;     dbname: hstore_test
;     TOC Entries: 15
;     Compression: -1
;     Dump Version: 1.12-0
;     Format: CUSTOM
;     Integer: 4 bytes
;     Offset: 8 bytes
;     Dumped from database version: 9.3.0
;     Dumped by pg_dump version: 9.3.0
;
;
; Selected TOC Entries:
;
2074; 1262 1358002 DATABASE - hstore_test xxxx
7; 2615 1358003 SCHEMA - hstore_test_schema xxxx
5; 2615 2200 SCHEMA - public postgres
2075; 0 0 COMMENT - SCHEMA public postgres
2076; 0 0 ACL - public postgres
173; 3079 11787 EXTENSION - plpgsql 
2077; 0 0 COMMENT - EXTENSION plpgsql 
174; 3079 1358004 EXTENSION - hstore 
2078; 0 0 COMMENT - EXTENSION hstore 
171; 1259 1358124 TABLE hstore_test_schema hstore_test_table xxxx
172; 1259 1358132 VIEW hstore_test_schema hstore_test_view xxxx
2069; 0 1358124 TABLE DATA hstore_test_schema hstore_test_table xxxx
1960; 2606 1358131 CONSTRAINT hstore_test_schema hstore_test_table_pkey xxxx
```

Incidentally, replacing the `NULLIF(col1, col2)` with `col1 = col2` seems to make the error disappear, despite the fact it's an explicit comparison of the type `pg_restore` was complaining of.

Comment: I'm raising this on pgsql-bugs now.

Comment: [The report to pgsql-bugs](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/53702D20.4070505@2ndquadrant.com).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a PostgreSQL bug. [I have relayed your report to the pgsql-bugs list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/53702D20.4070505@2ndquadrant.com).

What's happening is that `pg_dump` is setting the `search_path` to exclude `public` when creating tables in your schema. This is normal. When it dumps objects that refer to things that aren't on the `search_path`, it explicitly schema-qualifies them so they work.

It works for the `=` case because `pg_dump` sees that `=` is actually `OPERATOR(public.=)` in this case, and dumps it in that form:

```
CREATE VIEW hstore_test_view AS
 SELECT (hstore_test_table.column1 OPERATOR(public.=) hstore_test_table.column2) AS comparison
   FROM hstore_test_table;
```

however, `pg_dump` fails to do this for the operator implicitly used via the `nullif` pseudo-function. That results in the following bogus command sequence:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS hstore WITH SCHEMA public;
...
SET search_path = hstore_test_schema, pg_catalog;
...
CREATE VIEW hstore_test_view AS
 SELECT NULLIF(hstore_test_table.column1, hstore_test_table.column2) AS comparison
   FROM hstore_test_table;
```

`pg_dump` just uses the `pg_catalog.pg_get_viewdef` function to dump the view, so this probably requires a server backend fix.

The simplest workaround is not to use `nullif`, replacing it with a more verbose but equivalent `case`:

```
CASE WHEN column1 = column2 THEN NULL ELSE column1 END;
```

The syntax doesn't provide a way to schema-qualify the `nullif` pseudo-function's operator like we do with explicit `OPERATOR(public.=)`, so the fix doesn't appear to be trivial.

I expected the same issue to affect `GREATEST` and `LEAST`, perhaps also `DISTINCT`, but it doesn't. Both seem to find their required operators even when they aren't on the `search_path` at runtime, but don't fail if the operator isn't on the search_path at view definition time. That suggests they're probably using the type's b-tree operator class to look up the operators, via the type's entry in the catalogs as found via the table's attributes. (Update: checked the sources and yes, that's what they do). Presumably `nullif` should also be doing this, but isn't.

Instead it dies in:

```
hstore_test=# \set VERBOSITY verbose
hstore_test=# CREATE VIEW hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_view AS
SELECT NULLIF(column1, column2) AS comparison FROM hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_table;
ERROR:  42883: operator does not exist: public.hstore = public.hstore
LINE 2: SELECT NULLIF(column1, column2) AS comparison FROM hstore_te...
               ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
LOCATION:  op_error, parse_oper.c:722
```

which when I set a breakpoint there, traps at:

```
Breakpoint 1, op_error (pstate=pstate@entry=0x1189f38, op=op@entry=0x1189c10, oprkind=oprkind@entry=98 'b', arg1=arg1@entry=97207, arg2=arg2@entry=97207, 
    fdresult=FUNCDETAIL_NOTFOUND, location=location@entry=58) at parse_oper.c:706
706     {
(gdb) bt
#0  op_error (pstate=pstate@entry=0x1189f38, op=op@entry=0x1189c10, oprkind=oprkind@entry=98 'b', arg1=arg1@entry=97207, arg2=arg2@entry=97207, fdresult=FUNCDETAIL_NOTFOUND, 
    location=location@entry=58) at parse_oper.c:706
#1  0x000000000051a81b in oper (pstate=pstate@entry=0x1189f38, opname=opname@entry=0x1189c10, ltypeId=ltypeId@entry=97207, rtypeId=rtypeId@entry=97207, 
    noError=noError@entry=0 '\000', location=location@entry=58) at parse_oper.c:440
#2  0x000000000051ad34 in make_op (pstate=pstate@entry=0x1189f38, opname=0x1189c10, ltree=ltree@entry=0x118a528, rtree=0x118a590, location=58) at parse_oper.c:770
#3  0x00000000005155e1 in transformAExprNullIf (a=0x1189bc0, pstate=0x1189f38) at parse_expr.c:1021
#4  transformExprRecurse (pstate=pstate@entry=0x1189f38, expr=0x1189bc0) at parse_expr.c:244
#5  0x0000000000517484 in transformExpr (pstate=0x1189f38, expr=<optimized out>, exprKind=exprKind@entry=EXPR_KIND_SELECT_TARGET) at parse_expr.c:116
#6  0x000000000051ff30 in transformTargetEntry (pstate=pstate@entry=0x1189f38, node=0x1189bc0, expr=expr@entry=0x0, exprKind=exprKind@entry=EXPR_KIND_SELECT_TARGET, 
    colname=0x1189ba0 "comparison", resjunk=resjunk@entry=0 '\000') at parse_target.c:94
#7  0x00000000005212df in transformTargetList (pstate=pstate@entry=0x1189f38, targetlist=<optimized out>, exprKind=exprKind@entry=EXPR_KIND_SELECT_TARGET)
    at parse_target.c:167
#8  0x00000000004ef594 in transformSelectStmt (stmt=0x11899f0, pstate=0x1189f38) at analyze.c:942
#9  transformStmt (pstate=0x1189f38, parseTree=0x11899f0) at analyze.c:243
#10 0x00000000004f0a2d in parse_analyze (parseTree=0x11899f0, 
    sourceText=sourceText@entry=0x114e6b0 "CREATE VIEW hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_view AS\nSELECT NULLIF(column1, column2) AS comparison FROM hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_table;", paramTypes=paramTypes@entry=0x0, numParams=numParams@entry=0) at analyze.c:100
#11 0x000000000057cc4e in DefineView (stmt=stmt@entry=0x114f7e8, 
    queryString=queryString@entry=0x114e6b0 "CREATE VIEW hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_view AS\nSELECT NULLIF(column1, column2) AS comparison FROM hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_table;") at view.c:385
#12 0x000000000065b1cf in ProcessUtilitySlow (parsetree=parsetree@entry=0x114f7e8, 
    queryString=0x114e6b0 "CREATE VIEW hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_view AS\nSELECT NULLIF(column1, column2) AS comparison FROM hstore_test_schema.hstore_test_table;", 
    context=<optimized out>, params=params@entry=0x0, completionTag=completionTag@entry=0x7fffc98c9990 "", dest=<optimized out>) at utility.c:1207
#13 0x000000000065a54e in standard_ProcessUtility (parsetree=0x114f7e8, queryString=<optimized out>, context=<optimized out>, params=0x0, dest=<optimized out>, 
    completionTag=0x7fffc98c9990 "") at utility.c:829
```

so the immediate issue looks like `transformAExprNullIf` failing to look up the operator using the type of its operand via the b-tree opclass and the typecache.

Comment: 2019 and the bug is still present when exporting from PostgreSQL 10.6 and importing into 10.7 

Comment: @oᴉɹǝɥɔ Thanks for mentioning that. I'll look into it.